# How to get the iteration index on text.phtm

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I created 2 text fields from the custom options

[image]

The input from this text fields is used to call a third party js library.
Every time that the `oniput` event is triggered, this library should be called.
So I modified the following file:

> app/design/frontend/alonoraure/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml

```
?>
<?php $_option = $this->getOption(); ?>
<dt><label<?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></label>
    <?php echo $this->getFormatedPrice() ?></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
    <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_FIELD): ?>
        <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"  oninput="engraver.setText(1,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)"  <?php if ($_option->getMaxCharacters()): ?> maxlength="<?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ?>" <?php endif ?> id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" class="input-text<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>" />
    <?php elseif ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA): ?>
        <textarea id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" rows="5" cols="25"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?></textarea>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_option->getMaxCharacters()): ?>
        <p class="note"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum number of characters:')?> <strong><?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</dd>
```

as you can see, this is the line in question

```
oninput="engraver.setText(1,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)
```

The problem is that I'm calling `engraver.setText(1` for the 2 text fields, but the 1 should be the index of the iteration.

So for the first text filed that should be 1, but for the second it should be 2 and so on.
My question is: how could I access an index iterator so I can remove the hardcoded 1 and replace it with the iteratior index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend upon how many iterations you want.

If you know how many iteration then:

```
<?php $numberOfIteration = 5; //you can change this number to any number?>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfIteration; $i++):?>
    <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"  oninput="engraver.setText(<?php echo $i;?>,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)" ..... />
<?php endfor;?>
```

I believe you have `$options` somewhere in your code. That array will help to find how many iteration you want. You can do like this:

```
<?php $numberOfIteration = count($options); //$options = $product->getOptions();?>
```

Hope I understood your qst. Good Luck.

**UPDATE 1**

Alright, I think workaround is, you have to use sorting.
First in product backend, add `sorting` for each option. Sorting starting from 1.

Now

```
<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"  oninput="engraver.setText(<?php echo $_option->getSortOrder();?>,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)" ..... />
```

This should give you, whatever sorting number you give in backend.

Comment: That was very helpful Adarsh! The thing is that if I implement a foreach iterator as you say I'll end up  having 4 textfields instead of 2. 
It seems that there is a loop somwere else in Magento, that causes the line   `<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"  oninput="engraver.setText(1,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)" ..... />` to be repeated as many times as you define it on the Custom options in the admin panel. Do you know where that loop is implemented, because I believe that I might get the iteration index from there directly.

Comment: Plez add `app/design/frontend/alonoraure/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml` full code to your qst.

Comment: How about doing this: `<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"  oninput="engraver.setText(<?php echo $_option->getId();?>,document.getElementById('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text').value)" ..... />`. And obviously you will need to change your js code. Could you add js code too.

Comment: well I could do that, but $_option->getId() will return some number like 5331, and I'd like to get the custom option index (1,2,etc). 
Is there any way to inspect the $_option object, I might be able to find something useful there

Comment: Check my update.